# D3 treemap call resulting in NaN x0, x1, y0, y1 values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm building a D3 [treemap](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#treemap) visualization, and I've run into a spot of trouble.

I've been able to populate my initial treemap, but I'd like to introduce modifications to it via click interactions. In order to do that, I need to recompute a new layout (and then do some things with it later) every click, using a subset of my previous (currently displayed) data to do that.

I've written a [sum](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#node_sum) function that works as I want it to, and populates the `value` property of each `Node` in my `new_root` object. This is, as I understand it, the sole prerequisite for running `d3.treemap` on my `new_root` Here's a snippet of the code:

```
let treemap = d3.treemap()
    .tile(d3.treemapResquarify)
    .size([800, 400])
    .round(true)
    .paddingInner(1);

// later...

function object_is_direct_child(root, obj) {
    return (root.children.filter(child => (child.id === obj.name)).length > 0);
}

// ...much later...

// Create and bind the click event.
let click = function(d) {
    if (d.data.children.length > 0) {
        // Use the hover ID to get the underlying name attr (e.g. "Noise-hover" -> "Noise")
        let name = this.getAttribute("id").slice(0,-6);

        // Select the new root node.
        let new_root = root.children.find(c => c.id === name);

        // Sum.
        new_root = new_root.sum(node => ((object_is_direct_child(new_root, node)) ? node.n : 0));

        // Here is the problem area. This doesn't work as expected.
        treemap(new_root);            
    }
}

hover_rects.on("click", click);
```

This *should* populate the computed, liad-out `x0, x1, y0, y1` values on `new_node` and all of its sub-children. Instead, `new_node` and all of its children are NaN.

I've uploaded what I have so far as a Gist, [accessible here](https://gist.github.com/ResidentMario/2b78c27de7ec8af07f7e292e66ed8c03).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to debug this using the follow MWE script, run in Node:

```
'use strict';

// Load data.
const tree = require('../threshold-tree');
const d3 = require('d3');
const assert = require('assert');

// Load in the data file as it would be loaded in the browser.
const fs = require('fs');
const csvString = fs.readFileSync('data/complaint_types.csv').toString();
const raw_data = d3.csvParse(csvString);

let tr = new tree.ThresholdTree(raw_data);
let hr = tr.as_hierarchy();
let root = d3.stratify().id(d => d.name).parentId(d => d.parent)(hr);

function object_is_direct_child(root, obj) {
    return (root.children.filter(child => (child.id === obj.name)).length > 0);
}

// Now the sum function itself.
function nodal_summer(node) {
    return ((object_is_direct_child(root, node)) ? node.n : 0);
}

root = root.sum(nodal_summer);

// Create our treemap layout factory function.
let treemap = d3.treemap()
    .tile(d3.treemapResquarify)
    .size([800, 400])
    .round(true)
    .paddingInner(1);

// Apply our treemap function to our data.
debugger;
treemap(root);

// Again...this is where it fails!
let new_root = root.children[0];
new_root.parent = null;
new_root = new_root.sum(node => ((object_is_direct_child(new_root, node)) ? node.n : 0));

debugger;
new_root = treemap(new_root);
console.log(treemap(new_root));
```

The culprit is the `positionNode` callback inside `d3`:

```
  function positionNode(node) {
    var p = paddingStack[node.depth],
    ...
```

`paddingStack` is initialized as a length-1 list, but  `node.depth` is `1`, so `p` is initialized as `NaN`, which gets propagated from there.

Two working fixes are:

1. Using `node.copy()`.
2. `new_root.eachBefore(function(node) { node.depth--; })`.